# How to Remove a Tab from showing on Product views?? (Magento 1.9)

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, design, tabs, frontend-error

Currently, our product pages are appearing with a size guide tab that we do not want to show,

[[image: Size Guide tab Appearing[1]]

I need to know what I can do to stop this tab from showing?

Where would the location of the code that makes this tab appear be?

Where are the tabs declared??

Answer (score 0):

You can remove product page tabs via XML, add a local.xaml file to your theme if you already don't have one **app/design/frontend/[your_package]/[your_theme]**

In the local.xml file remove product tabs using the following XML:

Looks like that is the Additional information tab so try

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<layout version="0.1.0">

<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info.tabs">
        <action method="unsetChild">
            <child>additional</child>
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>

</layout>
```